# Memory and performance impact with class and instance methods

Tags: ruby, memory, optimization, memory-management

When I have a class that contains several self methods and non-self methods like below:

```
class Employee
  def self.hello
    puts "greet our employee"
  end

  def not_self
    puts "this is not a self method"
  end
end
```

If the `not_self` method is called through `Employee.new.not_self`, will all the class methods still be loaded in the memory and is there performance impact?

Comment: The correct terms are **class method** and **instance method**.

Comment: The methods will be created ("loaded into memory") as soon as Ruby evaluates the method definitions, i.e. when the file containing the above code (e.g. `employee.rb`) is loaded. If you don't want Ruby to evaluate the class methods, you could move them into another file (by reopening the `Employee` class or by defining them in a separate module) and require that file when needed. (although this will hardly have any significant effect, memory and performance-wise)

Comment: BTW, if Ruby would not load the class methods, you couldn't call `Employee.new` – `new` is a class method.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan for the reply, so if both the methods are in the same class and i call Employee.new.not_self will self.hello be also available in the memory?

Comment: Yes. But that doesn't cause any problems. Maybe you are under the impression that the methods are being copied into the instance each time you create a new instance? That is not the case – each method is stored only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the `not_self` method is called through `Employee.new.not_self`, will all the class methods still be loaded in the memory [...]

When Ruby evaluates your code, it creates a new class and assigns it to the constant `Employee`. It then creates two methods `hello` and `not_self`.

The methods are created by defining them (via `def ...`), not by calling them. Whether you call them afterwards is irrelevant.

> [...] and is there performance impact?

Not really, since the methods are stored only once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the methods are stored only once, but, say a object is created it would have its own copy of methods, so will other instances. i.e. each object will have its own copy of instance methods. but when the class has many self methods will all those be loaded in memory, even if they are never called? sorry not sure if i am able to ask the question correctly, hopefully you know what i mean.

Comment: @opensource-developer _"each object will have its own copy of instance methods"_ – no. The methods are stored in classes and modules, not in the objects themselves. Creating 1,000 instances does **not** create 1,000 copies of the instance methods.

Comment: so, as in the example i mentioned above, If i have n number of class methods defined and i call a instance method like Employee.new.method_1 wouldn't the class methods be loaded in the memory for that instance or they are loaded only when the are called?

Comment: @opensource-developer methods are created ("loaded into memory") the moment they are defined via `def`.